# Shortest Distances To One Of Multiple Potential Destinations

Tags: algorithm

I was asked on a programming test to solve a problem where I had to find the shortest distance from each node on a rectangular graph to one of a set of possible destinations on the graph.  I was able to create a solution that passed all the tests but I'm fairly certain there is a more efficient algorithm out there.

```
C11--C12--C13--C14
 |    |    |    |
FGB--C22--C23--C24
 |    |    |    |
C31--C32--C33--C34
 |    |    |    |
C41--FGB--C43--C44
 |    |    |    |
C51--C52--C53--C54
 |    |    |    |
C61--C62--C63--FGB
```

So for example, on the graph above, say each "FGB" represents a Five Guys (because it's delicious).  And each "Cxx" represents a customer.  It was essentially, "How far is each customer from the nearest Five Guys?"  So C11 is 1 away, C12 is 2 away, etc.  All edges are weight=1.

Is [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) what I'm looking for?  I don't really care about all pairs.

Any thoughts or reference materials you might point me to?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something, or can you just calculate the distance from the coordinates of each point, that is the distance from (x, y) to (x', y') is abs (x - x') + abs (y - y')?

Comment: Do a BFS starting from the FGBs.

Comment: Yeah @gnasher729 so for each Cxx you'd repeat that for each FGB, right?  So isn't that O(m*n)?

Comment: Does the graph always have this matrix layout, where each internal node has 4 neighbours, which are the nodes directly north, east, south and west of it? Or is this just an example, and could the graph have any number of neighbours, unrelated to the position in the displayed format?

Comment: The graph always has this rectangular layout, but it could be any size and could have any number of FGB's.  Any node that isn't an FGB is a customer.  You know the coordinates of the FGB's to start (you don't have to search for them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple solution that works in two passes.

The firt pass is forward, row by row. For every node, you evaluate incrementally the distance to the nearest target to the left of above.

```
D(node)= if target node => 0 else min(D(left neighbor) + 1, D(top neighbor) + 1)
```

The second pass is backward. The final distance is evaluated as

```
D(node)= min(D(node), D(right neighbor) + 1, D(bottom neighbor) + 1)
```

At the same time that you record a new value, you can record the location of the corresponding target.

(When a neighbor does not exist, the distance is infinite by convention.)

Comment: Thanks @yves-daoust.  I tried to comment here but my response was too long, so I made a new answer to respond to you.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38172165/5971378  This seems embarrassingly simple compared to what I came up with.  Kind of wish I had a time machine.  You live you learn.

Comment: @CashStramel: this is a known problem in digital image processing. It computes the "topological distance to a binary image". Interestingly, it is also possible to compute the Euclidean distance in time proportional to the number of pixels; this is more complicated, though. See "Distance Transforms of Sampled Functions, P. Felzenszwalb, D. Huttenlocher, Theory of Computing, Vol. 8, No. 19, September 2012"

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary graph size, with an arbitrary number of target nodes (FGBs), the following BFS algorithm will be the most efficient:

```
nodes = set of all nodes
currentNodes = set of target nodes (FGB)

for each node in nodes:
    dist[node] = infinity

for each node in currentNodes:
    dist[node] = 0

while currentNodes is not empty:
    newNodes := []
    for each node in currentNodes:
        for each neighbor of node:
            if dist[neighbor] > dist[node] + 1 then:
                dist[neighbor] := dist[node] + 1
                newNodes.add(neighbor)
    currentNodes := newNodes
```

The `for each node` loop will in total visit every node exactly once.

The `for each neighbor` loop will iterate at the most 4 times per node, given the graph is a rectangular one.

This means the inner `if` condition will be executed near **4n** times, i.e. this is *O(n)*. Depending on the used data structure the number can be **4n-4√n** as the boundary nodes have fewer neighbors, but this is still *O(n)*.

Note that if you have fewer than 4 target nodes (FGBs) it will be faster (though not significant in big-O terms) to use the rectangular properties of the graph to calculate the distances. You could do that with this formula, where **m** is the number of target nodes (FGBs):

```
dist[node at [i,j]] := min( abs(i-FGB[0].column)+abs(j-FGB[0].row),
                            abs(i-FGB[1].column)+abs(j-FGB[1].row),
                            ... 
                            abs(i-FGB[m-1].column)+abs(j-FGB[m-1].row)
                          )
```

This has a time complexity of *O(n.m)*, which for a **m** limited to a certain constant still is *O(n)* and might be faster than the more generic solution.

An algorithm could make use of this, and depending on the value of **m**, could choose which method to apply.

Comment: You don't need the check `if dist[neighbor]...`, because all the weights are 1

Comment: @anatolyg. In this algorithm, `dist[neighor]` is not the distance from the node to its neighbor, but the distance of the neighbor to the nearest target cell, which at the start is set to infinity or zero. The test is practically equivalent to `dist[neighbor] == infinity`, but that looks a bit odd from a mathematical point of view, so I just did the greater-than check.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @yves-daoust (I know I'm not suppose to respond to other answers with a whole new answer, but this is too long for the "response to answer" dialog box).

So the whole thing would look something like this?

```
// O(n)
for each node:
  set node distance to infinity

// O(m)
for each FGB in FGB coordinate list
  directly set corresponding node distance to infinity

// O(n)  
for each i in row
  for each j in column
    if left and up exist
      set node(i,j) to min(node(i,j), left+1, up+1)
    else if left exists
      set node(i,j) to min(node(i,j), left+1)
    else if up exists
      set node(i,j) to min(node(i,j), up+1)

// O(n)
for each i in row (reverse)
  for each j in column (reverse)
    if right and down exist
      set node(i,j) to min(node(i,j), right+1, down+1)
    else if right exists
      set node(i,j) to min(node(i,j), right+1)
    else if down exists
      set node(i,j) to min(node(i,j), down+1)
```

The whole thing is O(3n+m) = O(n+m).  Is that right?

Comment: The complexity is O(n.m), not O(n+m), as there are nested loops. This is unavoidable as one must read all elements at least once.

Comment: I can see the nested loops over (i, j) as locally being seen as O(i.j), but that's just the mechanism that allows me to evaluate each node n one time.  So from a higher level, it's not O(n) for each pass?

Comment: Oooops, sorry, I misunderstood the meaning of m and n. As m<=n, the asymptotic complexity is indeed O(n), m can be absorbed in n.